# Ambiguous tag: auto-rotation

Tags: discussion, tags

I was about to edit the tag summary for [auto-rotation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auto-rotation), but then realized it has two different meaning in context of aviation. One for [helicopters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorotation), and another for [fixed-wing aircraft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorotation_%28fixed-wing_aircraft%29).

Should one or the other get preference? Or should we really create two separate, but equal tags (e.g. [autorotation-helicopter](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autorotation-helicopter) and [autorotation-fixed-wing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autorotation-fixed-wing))?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe it's just me, but I've actually never heard of the second use (for fixed wing aircraft).

I would suggest using [autorotation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autorotation) for helicopters and [spin](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spin) for the fixed wing version.  There won't be any confusion if the tag wikis are properly written.

If it is a more common term than I realize, the tag wikis could point to each other (in autorotation we could include a comment that says something like "if you are looking for fixed-wing autorotation (also known as a spin), see [spin](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spin), and vice-versa.

Comment: I've never heard the second sense used either - I've always heard it described as an "incipient spin".

Comment: I've heard it used, but it's pretty uncommon - and there are usually a lot of other terms used with it.

Comment: And here I thought "autorotation" in the context of fixed-wing aircraft meant an aircraft with an excessively-aft CoM spontaneously rotating during takeoff.